# Неверное отображение русских букв в текстовом файле

Tags: linux, ubuntu, кодировка

При переходе с Windows 10 на Ubuntu 18.04 предварительно перекинул все необходимые файлы в облако мейла.

После установки ОС скачал их и заметил, что содержимое всех .txt-файлов с русским текстом сменилось на непонятные символы (скриншот). Понял, что что-то не так с кодировкой, проверил её. У всех файлов стоит кодировка либо iso-8859-1(в которой нет русских букв) или unknown-8bit. Пробовал менять кодировку на utf-8, но не получил никакого положительного результата.

Можно ли каким-нибудь? образом можно восстановить эти файлы?

[image: ...]

Comment: Использовать кодировку Windows-1251 — https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=33911.0 — https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_gedit

Comment: 1. для приведённого примера: `$ cat файл | iconv -t iso8859-1 | iconv -f cp1251` 2. текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, практически наверняка в 8859-1 файл уже редактор загнал, так что последнего хватит...